# Converting a simple df to a ts object that is aggregated by year

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a df of the following:

```
structure(list(Type = c("Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", 
"Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", 
"Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", 
"Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", 
"Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", 
"Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", 
"Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", 
"Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4", "Type 4"), 
    Year = c(1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
    1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
    2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
    2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
    2021, 2022, 2023, 1986, 1987, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
    1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
    2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
    2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 1982, 1984, 
    1985, 1987, 1988, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
    1998, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
    2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
    2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
    2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
    2023), Rolling_Sum = c(2, 1.65, 2.8, 0.65, 2.1, 4.7, 0.8, 
    1.65, 3.95, 7.3, 13.45, 7.6, 11.35, 14.25, 9.475, 5.65, 6.22, 
    5.945, 8.22, 9.102, 14.35, 17.7, 27.391, 29.15, 35.2, 63.627, 
    94.592869, 71.638245, 71.616951, 70.640088, 60.114466, 54.180581, 
    49.588879, 55.028252, 50.848614, 48.744727, 32.235111, 105.109657, 
    88.073521, 82.361093, 6, 0.05, 0.1, 0.65, 5.7, 20.15, 6.6, 
    11.7, 6.7, 9.725, 4.95, 3.125, 0.435, 3.37, 9.225, 13.575, 
    8.925, 13.4, 19.05, 13.5, 38.871, 79.895962, 49.904916, 43.987515, 
    43.12883, 36.506245, 38.223299, 30.297244, 32.444623, 32.109065, 
    27.894704, 31.563774, 147.750757, 79.620748, 59.666394, 7.898425, 
    1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.65, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 2.35, 
    0.35, 2.5, 3.669, 18.925, 9, 18.49, 10.5, 10.25, 44.414, 
    76.488204, 46.723932, 49.309076, 54.921755, 50.647539, 41.255551, 
    31.381031, 37.768795, 29.27807, 28.434694, 35.099662, 128.568204, 
    48.105376, 40.714246, 3.5, 0.661, 8.5, 2.829, 22.755, 20.187569, 
    8.5297, 7.447, 6.04, 1.75, 3.428, 1.597, 5.966365, 2.05, 
    35.301736, 15.749993, 33.923156, 4.44075)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -129L), groups = structure(list(
    Type = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:41, 42:76, 77:112, 113:129), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I've effectively aggregated a much larger dataset by year and type. I'd now like to convert the dataframe into a time series object using the ts() function using the stats library.

Unfortunately I keep running into errors because the function seem to like having a year time series, how can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to a zoo object and then to ts:

```
library(zoo)
df |> read.zoo(index = "Year", split = "Type") |> as.ts()
```

giving

```
Time Series:
Start = 1981 
End = 2023 
Frequency = 1 
        Type 1     Type 2    Type 3    Type 4
1981   2.00000         NA        NA        NA
1982   1.65000         NA   1.00000        NA
1983   2.80000         NA        NA        NA
1984   0.65000         NA   0.40000        NA
1985   2.10000         NA   0.10000        NA
1986   4.70000   0.050000        NA        NA
1987   0.80000   0.100000   0.40000        NA
1988   1.65000         NA   0.65000        NA
1989        NA         NA        NA        NA
1990        NA         NA        NA        NA
1991   3.95000   0.650000   0.20000        NA
1992   7.30000   5.700000   0.50000        NA
1993  13.45000  20.150000   0.40000        NA
1994   7.60000   6.600000   0.10000        NA
1995  11.35000  11.700000   0.10000        NA
1996  14.25000   6.700000   0.80000        NA
...snip...
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I seem to be getting a "Error: unexpected '>' in "df |>"" error with the code you've written, why is this (apologies, not particularly familiar with zoo)

Comment: You must be using a very old version of R which predated R pipes.  Either update to the latest version of R (preferred) or rewrite it without pipes:  `as.ts(read.zoo(df, index = "Year", split = "Type"))`

Comment: Using pipes as I understand them: df %>% read.zoo(index = "Year", split = "Type") %>% as.ts() delivers this error: Error in read(file, ...) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of zoo.